How to bootstrap the routing, NgRx etc of MFE module from the shell project forcibly using module federation?
I want to bootstrap or initiate the MFE's routing, NgRx and other library instances from the Shell project programatically.
Now I am doing lazy load of modules from shell as below
loadChildren: () =>
        loadRemoteModule({
            type: 'module',
            remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4300/remoteEntry.js',
            exposedModule: './MySubModule',
        }).then((m) => m.MySubModule),

Here all the stuffs configured in this module is loaded and initiated. But I want to make sure all the require configs for MFE are loaded.
How can I achieve this?
